# Should I chown after tar and mv file to different domain director on same server?

Tags: linux, wordpress, vhosts, mediatemple, chown

I performed a tar of an entire directory in httpdocs on one domain (reesefelts.org) and un-tar in another directory on the same vhosts machine at mediatemple (dev.reesefelts.org). Now having issues updating files using FTP and BBEdit. Can edit the files in BBEdit, but it won't save my changes.

When WordPress wouldn't see wp-config.php, I chown wp-config.php to the user for that domain. Do I need to change own for the entire "httpdocs" directory or just all files and folder recursively in httpdocs, and what is the command for that?

MediaTemple gives me this:

`chown domainuser:psaserv /var/www/vhosts/mt-example.com/myweb
chown -R domainuser:psacln /var/www/vhosts/mt-example.com/myweb/*`

Is this correct?

According to this, the first line is the current user for that domain. What's the command to find owner?

Then, the second line would be to change owner to the FTP user, is that right? So that way, the FTP user can edit a file using Fetch and BBEdit and save down the changes, right?

Also, I'm not able to write new plug-ins, upgrades, or any uploads to the wp-content directory. I'm assuming it's the same issue.

I'm new to Linux and am learning as I go. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you need to know owner, group and perms of the files that are causing problems.
To do that, simply do an `ls -l` on the dir and check that.
If you want to be able to edit and save the files from FTP, you need to know which group the FTP user have and change the group of the files, or change the owner and group or change the permissions.

You need to read about users, groups and permissions on linux, I recommend you to google about it and read a bit and you will be able to do it yourself.

BTW, the commands posted are fine, but not sure if they do the correct changes.

Comment: Thank you. I performed the ls -l operation and discovered that my files were not owned by the right user once I'd moved them from one httpsdocs directory for domain1 into the other httpdocs directory in domain2. I learned how to chown the directory, resetting the files to the FTP user of the domain2 and that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that you was able to do it!